# how to correctly display Chinese when LANG=en_US.UTF-8?

Tags: fonts

When using `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` the Chinese fonts look strange comparing to `LANG=zh_cn.UTF-8`. It seems like the fonts are coming from several different font files.
I tried the tricks like modify the 40-nolatin.conf and 65-nolatin.conf to move my preferred font to the top. But in ubuntu 20.04 it seems have no effect at all. Any idea how can I fix this in ubuntu 20.04?
[image]

Comment: Did you install other Chinese font packages besides `fonts-noto-cjk` which is there by default?

Comment: yes I installed wqy which is preferred. the noto-cjk is mostly for Japanese which missing many characters. But I do need to display Japanese so I need to keep it too.

Comment: Do I need to somehow change 64-language-selector-prefer.conf?

Comment: Possibly. Which wqy font? Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command (when you use a non-Chinese locale): `fc-match -a | head -70`

Comment: ah works! I need to put Noto Sans CJK SC and Noto Sans CJK TC in the front to make it work. But of cause, when I prefer to display JP I have to swap it back.

Comment: It sounds as if you prefer the Noto fonts after all. :)

Comment: Please write an answer so that it help others. If not, consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since current linux font system actually take the language into account, the correct way is to add/modify entries in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/64-language-selector-prefer.conf`

Comment: Thanks! I have used `<family>Noto Sans CJK JP</family>` for Chinese for some time，it is time to change to `<family>Noto Sans CJK CN</family>`.